# How to change li CSS in mpdf?

Tags: php, css, mpdf

I work with mPDF to generate invoices to send to my customers. I have an invoice that has some metadata that is listed using an li element. I want the dots from the li element to not be visible. I've tried applying 'list-style-type: none;' to the element in which this information is displayed. I've tried both 
of this inline and in the actual CSS.

```
    <?php
    foreach ( $invoice->get_columns_data() as $index => $row ) {
        echo '<tr class="item">';

        // Display row data.
        foreach ( $row as $column_key => $data ) {
            $templater->display_data_recursive( $column_key, $data );
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

The PDF ignores all changes to the metadata that is passed through, but it will change the tr element's background, for example.

```
.item {
list-style-type: none!important;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

list-style-type: none; will not work, even if I add !important
background-color: yellow; will work regardless.

[Example of element change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBSJ5.png)

I don't know what to do to get this element to listen to my CSS.

Could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction so I can continue?

Comment: Maybe actually show us what you tired then? The code you have shown so far doesn’t contain any of what you said - no LI, no `list-style-type` set anywhere … Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I've added my CSS, sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I’d check if the HTML & CSS you are creating there does what you want when viewed in the browser first. Then you’ll know whether it is an issue specific to the PDF creation, or some general mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add css line to local page:

```
.item{list-style-type: none!important;}
```

Or add new class like

```
//css  .nodots{list-style-type: none!important;}
//php   echo '<tr class="item nodots">';
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I did not supply the CSS I tried. I already tried this, it ignores it completely. It will show the background-color, though.

Comment: With !important ?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the original post it also ignores !important

Comment: I saw you code, but you use !important out of ''function", you must use !important like my code.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new, I was not aware that !important has to be added like that, rather than behind the semicolon. That being said, it does not change the list type.

Comment: have you tried : ul{list-style-type: none!important;}

Comment: I just tried this, it also does not work. I think the way mpdf works interferes with the CSS I provided. I understand the basics of CSS but my issue here lies with the fact that anything I tell it in regards to the text it prints is ignored. It will change the background color of the element, but not the color of the text or the style of the list.

Comment: The only solution it's find output of that code :  $templater->display_data_recursive( $column_key, $data ); 
and see which html output do and if have a class css for change dot list.
or in "extremis" use this code for reduce dot to 0 :
$this->list_symbol_size = '0pt';